# Does the pkg-config plugin not work with eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I just tried to use the pkg-config plugin for the first time since upgrading from eclipse luna to mars.  It seemed to work fine up until when I checked the box on some packages to include.  I got no error messages.  The only issue was that it did not add the includes and library to the compiler and linker settings.  I tried it on a fresh mars install as well and I had the same error.  I am using Ubuntu 15.10.  Anyone else have this issue or know how to fix it?  Also does anyone know an easy way to include all of the gtk options into eclipse without it.  I know I can just edit the command line to use pkg-config but then the auto complete in eclipse will not know about it.

UPDATE: I tried it with luna and now I get the same bug.  Maybe it was caused by upgrading from ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10

Comment: I e-mailed the developer of pkg-config plugin for Eclipse about the issue. Waiting for response.

Answer (score 1):

How I installed pkg-config for Eclipse Mars CDT was go to "Help->Install New Software..." click "Add" URL:

"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TuononenP/pkg-config.p2/master/site.xml"

Then "Next/Finish" After that it will install.